# Commandline e-mail client that syncs contacts with external server?

Tags: command-line, synchronization

I am planning to setup a groupware server that's either [Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php) or [SOGo](http://www.sogo.nu/), which supports the GroupDAV, CardDAV, or SyncML protocols.

Is there a commandline e-mail client that supports syncing contacts via such protocols either out of the box or with a plugin/extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of both of the software products you linked to ([here](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/documentation%3asystem_administration_manual#ldapdirectorysupport) and [here](http://www.sogo.nu/english/support/documentation.html)) both support storing directory information using LDAP.  If you do not find a command line email client that supports the protocols that you mentioned, you could try using LDAP instead.  Every decent email client supports LDAP.

Comment: OK, I will try to use LDAP, then. Thank you for the suggestion!